# how to get the specify items in byte() array in VB

Tags: vb.net

I am working on the VB.NET. I have two arrays need to compare and output the remainder of the longer array. I just simplify my question as following code:

```
Dim array1 As Byte() = {&H01, &H22,&H10,&HBC,&HA2,&H01,&H00,&HA6,&H02,&HBB,&H33,&H11,&HB2,&H01}
Dim array As Byte() = {&H01, &H22,&H10,&HBC,&HA2,&H01,&H00,&HA6,&H02,&HBB,&H33,&H11,&HB2,&H02,&H77,&H44,&HBF}
Dim remainder As Byte()
IF(array1.Length< array2.Length) then
  Dim remainderLength = array2.Length- array1.Length
  For...
  '''array1.Length =14
  '''array2.Length =17
  '''write the code to sign the last 3 Hex values into new array remainder and output the remainder
Next
```

the remainder length might be changed to other sizes, 100, 200 or more. I tried the Item()function and IndexOf()function, and didn't get the result. Please help to write the left code. The final result I want remainder = {&H77,&H44,&HBF}
thank you very much for any comments.

Comment: Why would it be any different with byte arrays than any other?  Have you tried anything at all?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to use LINQ's `Skip` extension method.

```
For Each b As Byte In array.Skip(array1.Length)
    Console.Write(b)
Next
```

Or:

```
Dim remainder As Byte() = array.Skip(array1.Length).ToArray()
```

You may also want to consider using the `Array.Copy` method which allows you to pass the starting index as an argument:

```
Array.Copy(array, array1.Length, remainder, 0, array.Length - array1.Length)
```

Or, if all else fails, it's always possible to access each item in the array by index:

```
For i As Integer = array1.Length to array.Length
    Console.Write(array(i))
Next
```

Comment: thanks for your response. but in array.Skip(array1.Length), what is "array" here?

Comment: I was using the same variables names as your example code in your question.  So, by `array`, I meant the `array` variable as declared and initialized in the code listed in your question.